# Assign a value, if a number is in between two numbers

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm trying to assign the value of -1, to every number in my vector that is in between 2 and 5.

I thought an if - then statement would work. I am having some trouble. I don't think (2<x<5) is right but I am not sure how to write in between in R. Can anyone help? Thanks

```
x <- c(3.2,6,7.8,1,3,2.5)
if (2<x<5){
    cat(-1)
} else {
    cat (x)
}
```

Answer (score 27):

There are a number of syntax error in your code.

Try using `findInterval`

```
x[findInterval(x, c(2,5)) == 1L] <- -1
x
## [1]  -1.0  6.0  7.8  1.0 -1.0 -1.0
```

read `?findInterval` for more details on the use of `findInterval`

You could also use `replace`

```
replace(x, x > 2 & x < 5, -1)
```

Note that

- for `2<x<5` you need to write `x > 2 & x < 5`
- `cat` will output to the console or a file / connection. It won't assign anything.

Comment: Thanks, thats actually the opposite of what I was looking for though. I am looking for 3.2,3 and 2.5 to be -1.. Also can you explain what the 2L means?

Comment: -- that was my error, the results should be correct now. 0 would be <2, 1 is 2<x<5 and 2  is > 5. 2L explicitly creates an integer (not really needed)

Answer (score 15):

You probably just want to replace those elements with -1.

```
> x[x > 2 & x < 5] <- -1; x
[1] -1.0  6.0  7.8  1.0 -1.0 -1.0
```

You could also use `ifelse`.

```
> ifelse(x > 2 & x < 5, -1, x)
[1] -1.0  6.0  7.8  1.0 -1.0 -1.0
```

Comment: Can the first example be stored in a vector?

Comment: Sorry. I see that there is a difference - the first example is in-place replacement, so we can continue with x losing the original. The second one returns a new vector with the result. I was expecting that they both return a new vector.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's right. To use the first as a new vector, you'd make a copy of x first.

Answer (score 3):

I compared the solutions with `microbenchmark`:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(TeachingDemos)

x = runif(100000) * 1000
microbenchmark(200 %<% x %<% 500
               , x > 200 & x < 500
               , findInterval(x, c(200, 500)) == 1
               , findInterval(x, c(200, 500)) == 1L
               , times = 1000L
               )
```

Here are the results:

```
                               expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
                  200 %<% x %<% 500 17.089646 17.747136 20.477348 18.910708 21.302945 113.71473  1000
                  x > 200 & x < 500  6.774338  7.092153  8.746814  7.233512  8.284603 103.64097  1000
  findInterval(x, c(200, 500)) == 1  3.578305  3.734023  5.724540  3.933615  6.777687  91.09649  1000
 findInterval(x, c(200, 500)) == 1L  2.042831  2.115266  2.920081  2.227426  2.434677  85.99866  1000
```

You should take `findInterval`.
Please consider to compare it to `1L` instead of `1`.
It is nearly twice as fast.

Answer (score 2):

My preference for assigning a value to a variable based on a clearly defined numeric interval is to use base R syntax:

```
 DF$NewVar[DF$LowerLimit <= DF$OriginalVar & DF$OriginalVar < DF$UpperLimit] = "Normal"
 DF$NewVar[DF$LowerLimit < DF$OriginalVar] = "Low"
 DF$NewVar[DF$OriginalVar >= DF$UpperLimit] = "High"
```

I think this syntax is clearer than any number of R functions, largely because the code can be quickly customized to specify inclusive vs exclusive intervals.  In practice, it's quite common to encounter situations where an interval can be defined as either inclusive (i.e., [-x to +x]) or exclusive (i.e., (-x to +x)) or a combination (i.e., [-x to +x)).

Additionally, base syntax provides clarity to the code if somebody else is reviewing it later.  Each unique library of functions seems to have its own peculiar and slightly different syntax to achieve the same level of specificity as clearly defining the intervals using base R syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach that is a little more similar to the original:

```
library(TeachingDemos)

x <- c(3.2,6,7.8,1,3,2.5)

(x <- ifelse( 2 %<% x %<% 5, -1, x ) )
```

Comment: Hi @GregSnow, could you please explain what `%<%` does?  I haven't seen this one before, does it vectorise the `<` operation, like `%in%` ?

Comment: @Elise, a full description is on the help page: `help("%<%", package=TeachingDemos)`.  But basically it allows chaining like above.  It does the same thing as `<` but attaches the original values as attributes and checks them when chained.

Comment: Great, I see now. Thanks!