# If statement- diagonal of matrix

Tags: r

Im trying to put -5 in the diagonal of my matrix. I am using if statements. But my if statment is wrong. Can anyone give me some help?

```
X= rbind(c(1.2,3.4,10.3),c(2,8,78),c(45,-36,8))
array(X,dim=c(3,3))
if (X != (1.2,8.0)){
    cat(X)
} else {
    cat(-5)
}
```

Comment: You really need to read the [introductory manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html). I'm serious. Not trying to be a jerk. Really. I promise. This is very similar to the question you deleted... and shows the same misunderstanding of `if` as [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12946070/271616).

Answer (score 3):

```
X <- rbind(c(1.2, 3.4, 10.3), c(2, 8, 78), c(45, -36, 8))
diag(X) <- -5
```

Joshua wasn't trying to be a jerk like they said - it's fairly obvious that you're new to R because a lot of what you've written just doesn't work.

The condition inside an if statement has to be of length 1 and it appears as if you're hoping to feed in the entire matrix.  There is a vectorized version of if and that is `ifelse` but it won't work like you want it to for your matrix.

`cat` prints to the console but it won't replace elements in your matrix for you.  You need to do some sort of replacement to actually accomplish that.

It's probably also not the best idea to try to just manually identify which elements are unique to the diagonal to do the replacement.  There are better ways - a few of them are found in the intro manual that Joshua linked to.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Dason, But I am trying to do this without using the diag function.

Comment: @Bill When is the assignment due?